# Spring Boot - How to define application.yml properties as application.properties

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to set up an s3 bucket with my Spring Boot webapp for adding/removing images.

The guide I am following uses the following application.yml properties:

```
amazonProperties:
  endpointUrl: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
  accessKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secretKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  bucketName: your-bucket-name
```

How can I define these properties in my application.properties file?

All help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to just split them in different lines in your `application.properties`:

```
amazonProperties.endpointUrl= https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
amazonProperties.accessKey= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
amazonProperties.secretKey= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
amazonProperties.bucketName= your-bucket-name
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using spring Spring Cloud AWS maven dependency

`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
</dependency>`

use the following properties in your `application.properties` file.

`cloud.aws.region.static=your region
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=your access key
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=your secret key
app.awsServices.bucketName=bucketName`

refer: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.3.RELEASE/multi/multi__basic_setup.html